# java.lang.ClassCastException: org.mockito.codegen.Throwable$MockitoMock$1720133689 cannot be cast to com..exception.myException

Tags: mockito, powermock

How to write Mockito for the below test code ?

```
@Override
public void onSkipInRead(Throwable t) {
    MyException ex = (MyException) t;
    myService.updateErrLog("ANC", "ANZ", "READ", null, t.getMessage(),"N", 0, ex.getWriterName(), ex.getJobId());
}
```

Test case

```
@Test
public myService test_onSkipInRead() {
    myService.updateErrLog(any(), any(), any(), any(), any(), any(), any(), any(), any());
    mySkipListener.onSkipInRead(t);

    verify(myService, atLeast(1)).updateErrLog(any(), any(), any(), any(), any(), any(), any(), any(), any());
}
```

Error

> java.lang.ClassCastException: org.mockito.codegen.Throwable$MockitoMock$1720133689 cannot be cast to com..exception.myException

Answer (score 0):

How is the variable "t" initialized in your test class?
I am guess it's type is "Throwable" and therefore Mockito is mocking only a Throwable exception but your onSkipInRead method is casting that to MyException.
Simply change the type of your t variable to MyException and you will be good I think.

On a different subject: you are call the updateErrLog on your service in your test code so Mockito will have registered at least one call to it. Then you verify that there is at least one call to that method. Even if your onSkipInRead method does not call the updateErrLog method, your test will still succeed and I don't think that this is what you want.
It may also we useful to test that the updateErrLog method is called with data that is stored in the MyException instead of using any() on all method arguments but that of course depends entirely on your business processes and needs.